# Comparar dos Strings en PHP

Tags: php, variables

Estoy siguiendo un curso de PHP y en el tema de la comparación de variables, cuando comparo dos con 'strcmp' no me sale `0` o `1`, me sale el número `32` y no entiendo el por qué.

Os pongo el ejemplo que estoy metiendo en VSC:

```php
$variable1="Casa";
$variable2="CASA";

$resultado=strcmp($variable1, $variable2);

echo "El resultado es " . $resultado;
```

¿Por qué sale el `32` en vez de hacer la comparación entre las dos variables?.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puede que falte contexto en tu código o que estés usando una versión muy antigua de PHP ¿?. Una prueba de esto, agregado `var_dump($resultado);` arroja: `int(1)`, no `int(32)` como dices.

Comment: Es recomendable que uses `var_dump` siempre para depurar. En este caso, también para descartar que no hay caracteres ocultos en tus cadenas puedes usar: `var_dump($variable1);` y `var_dump($variable2);`

Comment: Verifica si no tienes algún `echo`, `print_r` u otra salida previa (o posterior) al código que pones. PHP no salta de línea ni deja espacios entre impresiones a menos que explicitamente le coloques espaciadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) `strcmp` debe retornar

- `-1` si `$variable1` < `$variable2`
- `0` si `$variable1` == `$variable2`
- `1` si `$variable1` > `$variable2`

Los `-1` o `+1` representan un valor cualitativo a través de su signo, más que un valor cuantitativo (el valor número no representa nada en este caso)

La documentación indica que esto es así desde la versión `8.2.0`, lo cual me parece dudoso, yo con la `8.1.0` obtengo igualmente (`-1` y `+1`).

Lo que si es seguro es que existen otras implementaciones y/o versiones que entregan un número distinto a `-1 y +1`. Uno podría suponer que el número entregado sirve para algún algoritmo de ordenamiento. En cualquier caso, solo para comparar 2 `string` tu debes entender que lo importante es el signo. Si te entrega `32` quiere decir que `$variable1` > `$variable2`

**¿Por qué 32?**

El número entregado depende de la codificación, y toma la diferencia de las primeras 2 letras diferentes (de izquierda a derecha)

Las primeras 2 letras diferentes en tu caso, es la `c` y `C`, en ASCII:

- c es 99
- C es 67

`99 - 67 = 32`

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas. Efectivamente, Yussef, me estaba temiendo que era algo relacionado con el código ASCII pero... ¿Por qué al profesor en la explicación al poner lo mismo que a mi le aparece al ejecutar "El resultado es 1"? ¿Puede ser porque está utilizando Dreamweaver y yo lo estoy ejecutando en VSC y una versión más actualizada?.

Comment: @IBU Depende de la implementación de PHP (para windows, linux, etc), de la versión y de la codificación  (ASCII, UTF), pero NO creo que dependa del editor (VSC y dreamweaver) aunque puede influir la codificación de ellos.  Lo importante que debes entender es que no debes confiar nunca en el número que te entrega esta función si no que solo en su signo.

Comment: Esto también pasa en javascript (mira la advertencia que ponen en la documentación) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#description

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias por tu aclaración, Yussef. Me has sido de gran ayuda! :)